# Call a Flask app with gunicorn from python module

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I want start a Web app from a CLI something like that:

```
 user@server:~$ my_app web --start
```

Web project was developed with Flask, and I want execute the web app with gunicorn in deamon mode.

But I don't understand how to execute from python module the gunicorn command. The command is:

```
user@server:~$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000  wsgi:app --daemon
```

I thought the following function:

```
def start_server():
     command = "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app --daemon"
     subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Obviously it does not work. I want something that allows me to control server (start, status, stop and more) from a python module. It is possible?

Project Structure:

```
├── my_app
│   ├── cli
│   │   ├── cli_app.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── helpers.py
│   ├── __version__.py
│   └── web
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── services.py
│       ├── static/
│       ├── templates/
│       │   ├── index.html
│       ├── services.py
│       ├── wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with **os.chdir(here)** where **here** is the current directory where is wsgi module.

Something like this (server.py):

```
import os
import subprocess

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def start_server():
     os.chdir(here)
     command = "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app --daemon"
     subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Directory structure is:

```
├── my_app
│   ├── cli
│   │   ├── cli_app.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── helpers.py
│   ├── __version__.py
│   └── web
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── services.py
│       ├── static/
│       ├── templates/
│       │   ├── index.html
│       ├── server.py
│       ├── wsgi.py
```